# iOS store formated text in app

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new in iOS and for my first app I want to made a app that will store a lot of static text. I want that text to be desplay formated, with numerated paragraphs.

I wonder what approach take to store that text in app. The text wouldn't changed, so I have some doubts that CoreData is a good way to solve this problem.

Maybe there is another, better solution?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you also want to store the formatting? Or just the text?

Comment: Yes, I want store also formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are text is not dynamic or there is no manipulation or searching require then you can store your data in plist or plain text file. It will be easy to load.

So i think you can go with the simple text file in this case.